# IWICBitmapLock::GetStride method always returns the same value

Tags: c++, bitmap, wic

I have this code, which executes several times during runtime:

```
// Restore the bitmap from the copy
IWICBitmapLock *pLock = NULL;
UINT cbStride = 0;
hr = m_pWICBitmapCopy->GetSize(&uiWidth,&uiHeight);
WICRect rcLock = { 0, 0, uiWidth, uiHeight };
hr = m_pWICBitmapCopy->Lock(&rcLock, WICBitmapLockRead, &pLock);
hr = pLock->GetDataPointer(&cbBufferSize, &pv);
hr = pLock->GetStride(&cbStride);
m_pWICBitmap->Release();
hr = m_pWICImagingFactory->CreateBitmapFromMemory(uiWidth,uiHeight,GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,cbStride,cbBufferSize,pv,&m_pWICBitmap);
hr = pLock->Release();
```

`uiWidth` and `uiHeight` always different, the initial value is 3264 and 2448. Second time it could be e.g. 778 and 246.
But method `pLock->GetStride(&cbStride)` always returns the same stride value (in my case 13056). It causes that `CreateBitmapFromMemory()` method creates a corrupted bitmap. Other variables are changing correctly depending on bitmap dimensions. It looks like `pLock` cached stride value somewhere.

In [MSDN written](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee690166(v=vs.85).aspx) that, the stride value is specific to the IWICBitmapLock, not the bitmap. However, I did release pLock every time. So what could be the cause of such behavior?

The second way I could use to do the same is like this, but I want to understand what’s wrong with the code above.

```
m_pWICBitmap->Release();
m_pWICImagingFactory->CreateBitmapFromSource(m_pWICBitmapCopy, WICBitmapCacheOnDemand, &m_pWICBitmap);
```

Comment: Releasing a bitmap *before* releasing the lock is odd, avoid that.

Comment: I'm locking m_pWICBitmap**Copy** but releasing m_pWICBitmap

Comment: Sure, but it is likely to avoid copying where possible.  Just something I saw, easy for you to check.  Nothing I can actually test, you surely need to post decent repro code to get an answer.

Comment: MSDN doesn't say the stride will be different every time, just that it can, depending on the implementation. It could just be the stride that was passed to CreateBitmapFromMemory. So, I would guess the problem is elsewhere (I notice in this code you are not checking the value of hr, or the source bitmap's pixel format).

Comment: However, It could be different because dimensions of bitmap always different. e.g., it is impossible to have the stride over 13000 when picture width is 100 pixels.  As regards checking values, I just omit this checking to make the code a bit easy to read, it always returns S_OK.